# is this the right link_to rails syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to "Profile", @user %>
# => <a href="/users/1">Profile</a>
```

if i use the above code replacing "Profile" with "Category" and @user with @category/@subcategory what do I then point the html link `a href` etc to?

Comment: Just replace and see, you will get to know :)

Comment: Instead of asking this, make the change and see for yourself what error you will get and whether you are able to solve it. If not, paste it here and seek guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for this method [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

The first parameter of the `link_to` method is the displayed text.
Secondly, you can pass in a single instance of an object which will generate a link to the objects `#show` action.

You may however pass a link explicitly (most common in my opinion).
This can be done by using the Rails path-helpers (`user_path(@user)`) or by passing in a string.

In your example, if you exchange `@user` with `@category` it would link to the categories `#show` action instead (Assuming you have a `Category` model and `@category` isn't nil.

Again, have a look at the documentation of the `link_to` method and get familiar with it.